# A problem in python odd or even function. Returning True is not working

Tags: python, while-loop

```
def is_even(x) :
      while x:
           if x==0:
               return True
           elif x==1:
               return False
           x-=2
print(is_even(5)) 
print(is_even(6))
```

**output**
*False*
*None*

If the `x==0` is replace with `x==2` it works fine. Please explain why returning True is not working for `x==0`.

Comment: `while x` will only loop while `x` is truthy.  If `x` is `0`, then it will break out of the loop. See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/39983695/6779307

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the last iteration, `x` is reduced to `0` so the `while` loop is not entered, and the function is terminated. Since it doesn't explicitly return anything, it implicitly returns `None`, which is a false-y.

You could use a single `if` inside the `while` loop and use the `while`'s condiiton itself to indicate an even number:

```
def is_even(x) :
      while x:
           if x==1:
               return False
           x-=2
      return True
```

Comment: probably worth pointing out that if `x` will never hit exactly `1` or `0` (aka is not an integer, or is an integer `<0`, that this is just an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

If `x = 0`, then you fail your `while`check and break out of the loop before you can check `if x==0: return True`.

You should instead use the modulo function, which returns the remainder of division.

```
3 % 2 == 1  # Odds
5 % 2 == 1
7 % 2 == 1

2 % 2 == 0  # Evens
4 % 2 == 0
6 % 2 == 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Because when `x == 0` it fails your `while x` check (0 is not truthy), so it exits the loop before it checks your condition again.

BTW the normal way to check parity is with the modulus (`%`) operator.

```
x % 2 == 0  # is_even
x % 2 != 0  # is_odd
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use x as a condition `while x` that condition will be False if x equals 0.

The correct way should be:

```
def is_even(x):
      while True:
           if x==0:
               return True
           elif x==1:
               return False
           x-=2
```

Obviously this is a very weird way to check if a number is even, you can do:

```
def is_even(x):
      return not bool(x%2)
```

Comment: N.B. anytime your code is `if <predicate>: return True; else: return False` you can instead write `return <predicate>` (or at least `return bool(predicate)`)

Comment: Personally for clarity I would write `return x % 2 == 0` -- still short, no implicit conversion from int to bool

Answer (score 0):

In Python, integers have `True` and `False` values. Any integer that is not `0`, will always evaluate `True`, and `0` will evaluate `False`.

In your code you are using a `while` loop, which only runs if the subsequent statement evaluates `True`. When you check `while x`, if the value of `x` is `0` (due to the calculation inside the loop), your statement will be the same as `while False`, which will not run the code inside.

To avoid this issue you can use the `modulo` operation, which gives you the remainder of an operation. Hence, `x % 2` will return `0`, if `x` is even, and `1` if it is odd. You can make a check on that and return the correct value in fewer lines, using fewer operations.

```
return (x % 2 == 0)
```

The above statement will return `True` if there is no remainder, and `False` if there is.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
def is_even(x):
while x>=0:
    if x == 0:
        return True
    elif x == 1:
        return False
    x -= 2


print(is_even(5))
print(is_even(6))
```

in your code the loop terminates when x reaches 0, put a condition such that the loop runs even when x is 0

cheers